# Save query string in cookie

Tags: php

On every request to my page i want to store the query string value in cookie. I mean when:

```
$_GET['id'] = 28 to get 28.
```

Next time when:

```
$_GET['id'] is 36.
```

I want to get 36 and add it to 28. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you looked at the `setcookie` function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cookies as you mentioned, but depending on the workflow, you may want to use `$_SESSION` since it is generally more secure. Cookies can be modified by the client, and persist between visits. If that is your desired behavior, then [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) will be your best bet.

```
<?php
// The intval() function helps to ensure that numbers are being used, floatval() could work too
// Get current cookie value
$currentValue = intval($_COOKIE['CookieCounter']);
// Get new passed value
$incrementBy = intval($_GET['id']);
// Set the cookie and have it saved for 30 days
setcookie('CookieCounter', str($currentValue + $incrementBy), time()+60*60*24*30);
```

An alternative way of doing it is to use sessions.

> Sessions are a simple way to store data for individual users against a
>   unique session ID. This can be used to persist state information
>   between page requests. Session IDs are normally sent to the browser
>   via session cookies and the ID is used to retrieve existing session
>   data. The absence of an ID or session cookie lets PHP know to create a
>   new session, and generate a new session ID.

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
// Check if the session value is already set
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
  $_SESSION['count'] = intval($_GET['id']);
} else {
// Increment the session value
  $_SESSION['count'] += intval($_GET['id']);
}
```

However, cookies are changeable, and also can get removed by browser settings, etc. If you want it to be more secure and persist, I would use a database or other persistent data store.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will give it a try. I want to make last view posts/items by the user. I should use cookie or not

Comment: Depends on your intent. If it's to track the total number of posts over a long period of time, then I would use the last segment of my answer and store this in a database (you likely have one since you mentioned "posts").

Answer (score 0):

```
$value=$_COOKIE['TestCookie'];
setcookie("TestCookie", $value+$_GET['value'], time()+(10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
```

This will solve your issue. I set the expiration time of the cookie to be huge you can modify it.